# Compilation error on generating OpenAPI specification for a service containing Cache-Control annotation with private cache

Tags: ballerina

### Description

I'm running into the following compilation error when trying to build a ballerina service with cache-control annotation with `private` caching enabled.
Furhter, I'm running the `bal build --export-openapi` command to generate the **OpenAPI** spec for the service.

**Sample code:** (build fail)

```
type SampleHttpResponse record {|
    *http:Ok;
    string body;
|};

type ErrorResponse record {|
    *http:InternalServerError;
    string body;
|};

resource function get sample(@http:Header {name: "X-JWT-Assertion"} string jwtAssertion)
    returns @http:Cache {isPrivate: true} SampleHttpResponse|ErrorResponse {
    
    // ...
}
```

**Compilation error:**

```
error: compilation failed: The compiler extension 'io.ballerina.openapi.build.OpenAPIBuildCompilerPlugin' failed to complete. No value present
```

### Observations

Removing the `private` cache config from the the cache-control annotation resolves the issue. And the OpenAPI spec still gets generated for `maxAge` config in cache-control.

**Sample code:** (build success)

```
resource function get sample(@http:Header {name: "X-JWT-Assertion"} string jwtAssertion)
    returns @http:Cache SampleHttpResponse|ErrorResponse {
    
    // ...
}
```

```
resource function get sample(@http:Header {name: "X-JWT-Assertion"} string jwtAssertion)
    returns @http:Cache {maxAge: 86400} SampleHttpResponse|ErrorResponse {
    
    // ...
}
```

### Environment

- **OS:** MacOS 13.3.1 (22E261)
- **Arc:** Apple M1
- **Ballerina:** Swan Lake Update 4 (2201.4.1)

Comment: It seems the problem persists for any `boolean` type cache-control configs. Eg: `noCache: true`, `noStore: true`

Answer (score 1):

If you're experiencing an issue with the cache-control (`@http:Cache`) annotation where `isPrivate=true` has been enabled when using openAPI spec generation. There, we need to add value to the `privateFields` field also within `@http:Cache` annotation.